# Multiple paste after a cut in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Today I found out that Win7 doesn't support multiple pasting of files after cutting them. So, if you have a file A.ext and you want to cut it from its folder and place it in two different folders, you got to:

1. Cut and paste it from its folder to the another
2. Cut and paste it from the another folder to the next one

I hope you understood.

And the question is, obviously, why that happens. Is there a way you can pass over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of a cut and paste is of a move operation - you are taking the file from location A and moving to location B. Being able to create a copy in location C doesn't make sense with this meaning.

If you want to create multiple copies then you need to do just that - copy. So you copy the file from location A and the you can paste into location B, C, D, .. etc.

If you don't need the file in location A then you have to go back and delete it when you've created all the copies.

There are probably 3<sup>rd</sup> party extensions that will do what you want though.

Comment: That is ok but why they are stored in the clipboard if they are not going to be used again?

Comment: @Tsvetan - once the file is cut from it's original location it has to be stored *somewhere* before it's pasted, and the clipboard is as good as any.

Answer (score 1):

Nope There's no workaround for this. Because when you're cutting you are basically copying and deleting (i.e moving) the file.

You can't cut from A to B to C. It blanks out the paste when you right click.